# How to capture incoming requests for IIS & Tomcat using MS network monitor

Tags: asp.net, tomcat, iis, networking, network-programming

I have a web application which sends request to a tomcat server which further sends request to IIS.

Web application --> Tomcat service --> IIS service

All three are hosted on the same machine.

When I open the web application I would like to monitor what all request/response to tomcat and IIS. I am trying to use Microsoft Network Monitor. tried to the following filter settings

My tomcat is running on port 6432

```
tcp.port == 6432
OR
Payloadheader.LowerProtocol.port == 6432
```

But nothing is captured. Can anyone please tell me what settings I should be putting to capture only IIS & tomcat tranffic.

Atul

Comment: By default, Network Monitor does not support capturing loopback traffic. You might try to use ETL https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/canberrapfe/2012/03/30/capture-a-network-trace-without-installing-anything-capture-a-network-trace-of-a-reboot/

Comment: Try IIS Failed Request Tracing.  It can trace request/responses, it does not need to be failed requests.

Answer (score 0):

Try IIS Failed Request Tracing. It can trace request/responses, it does not need to be failed requests.